# jquery selectors - assign value selected to input text box immediately preceding

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I would like to assign value selected to input text box immediately preceding this list item selected.

```
<script>    
            /* select inventory item from list */   
            $('.cl_inventorySelect').live('click', function() {
               alert($(this).text());
               // assign value selected to input text box immediately preceding this list item selected.
               $(this).previousSiblingOrSomething().val($(this).text()); 
               return false;                
            });

</script>



    html:

        <input class="SRPR  name="SRPR" type="text">
        <ul class="myClass">
            <li><a href="#" class="cl_inventorySelect">168559</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="cl_inventorySelect">11322868</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="cl_inventorySelect">11382611</a></li>
            <li value="0"><a href="#" class="cl_inventorySelect">11119393</a></li>
        </ul>
```

for : Cybernate

Here is the simplified story: I create the text input by cloning some html text stored in a javascript variable.  I am also using jQuery Mobile.

```
section = "<div data-role='fieldcontain'>\n\
       <label>Serial No</label>\n\
           <input type='text' class='SRPR select' />\n\
           </div>\n\";

myTmpl = $(section);                    
myTmpl.appendTo("#placeholder"+glCurrentTab).trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$(this).previousSiblingOrSomething().val($(this).text());
```

with

```
$(this).prev(":text").val($(this).text());
```

Comment: not working - does it matter that the input box was dynamically created? Does the .live take this into account?

Comment: It should not matter, Can you post the HTML/code that generates the textbox?